# IOS: NSMutableString go to the head

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmutablestring

I have this code:

```
NSMutableString *printHead = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", firstTextField.text, secondTextField.text];
```

I want that my NSLog is:

```
"firstTextField text"
"secondTextField text"
```

and not
    "firstTextField text" "secondTextField text"

second textField should go to the head, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `\n`:

```
NSMutableString *printHead = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", firstTextField.text, secondTextField.text];
```